# Fast approach to do Summation in Compile[]?

Tags: matrix, image-processing

My code does massive Summation and Matrix multiplication

`Compile[]` has boosted it distinctly. But I read some literatures related to my program, It seems there are approches to make it even faster. Maybe it can be improved from optimizing MMA language or algorithm itself.

My code is below.

```
MomentComputing = 
 Compile[{{Mmax, _Integer}, {k, _Integer}, {image, _Real, 
    2}, {xLegendreP, _Real, 2}, {yLegendreP, _Real, 2}}, 
  Block[{m, n, width, momentMatrix},
   width = Length[image];
   momentMatrix = Table[0., {Mmax + 1}, {Mmax + 1}];
   Do[
momentMatrix[[m + 1, n + 1]] = ((2. (m - n) + 1.) (2. n + 1.)/((k k)*width width)) xLegendreP[[
        m - n + 1]].image.yLegendreP[[n + 1]], {m, 0, Mmax}, {n, 0, 
     m}];
   
   momentMatrix], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True,  
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
```

It should be better if I don't use any loop operations. But I can not figure out any other approaches. Probably matrix vector multiplication should be time-consuming as well.

Comment: As a general comment, matrix-vector multiplication is likely to be most efficient.  Unless you discard part of the result.  It's built on LAPACK and highly optimized.

Comment: What happens if you omit `momentMatrix` & its initialization and change the Do loop to return `Table[((2. (m - n) + 
      1.) (2. n + 1.)/((k k)*width width)) xLegendreP[[m - n + 
      1]].image.yLegendreP[[n + 1]], {m, 0, Mmax}, {n, 0, m}]`?  Ditto for `reconstructedImage`.

Comment: Including working test code would help you get better answers.

Comment: @MichaelE2  I just tried the your suggestion. Theorietically it should be faster, but it didn't make differences well. Maybe it is fast enough and can not be boosted any more.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Might be faster to do xLegendreP.image.Transpose[yLegendreP] and transpose, then shift row j by j-1 places rightward, then transpose back. Compute those multipliers separately (precomputing k^2*widh^2) and multiply matrices component-wise.

Comment: What dimensions have lPoly and lambdaMatrix? Can you give a reference on the reconstruction you are trying?

Comment: @Eisbär Yes, lPoly's dimension is `{101,256}`. I add the `lPoly` in part two. `lambdaMatrix` dimension is `{101,101}`, which is yielded from `MomentComputing`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First we run the original with an example (which should have been in the post).

```
Mmax = 400;
W = 1024;
deltaX = .1;
SeedRandom[1111];
lambdaMatrix = RandomReal[1, {W, W}];
lPoly = Developer`ToPackedArray[RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {Mmax + 1, W}]];

AbsoluteTiming[
 res = MomentComputing[Mmax, 5, lambdaMatrix, lPoly, lPoly];]

(* Out[52]= {12.1522, Null} *)
```

What I had in mind is this (I could combine some steps and maybe improve speed a bit further).

```
MomentComputing2 = 
  Compile[{{Mmax, _Integer}, {k, _Integer}, {image, _Real, 
     2}, {xLegendreP, _Real, 2}, {yLegendreP, _Real, 2}}, 
   Block[{m, n, width, mult, mat1, momentMatrix},
    width = Length[image];
    mult = 1./(k^2*width^2);
    mat1 = 
     Table[(2. (m - n) + 1.) (2. n + 1.), {m, 0, Mmax}, {n, 0, Mmax}]*
      mult;
    momentMatrix = Transpose[xLegendreP.image.Transpose[yLegendreP]];
    momentMatrix = 
     Transpose[
      MapIndexed[(PadLeft[Drop[#1, -(#2[[1]] - 1)], Mmax + 1, 0.]) &, 
       momentMatrix]];
    mat1*momentMatrix
    ], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
   Parallelization -> True, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
```

Repeat the example.

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 res2 = MomentComputing2[Mmax, 5, lambdaMatrix, lPoly, lPoly];]

(* Out[54]= {0.023139, Null} *)
```

Check that the results are within numeric fuzz:

In[57]:= Max[Abs[res - res2]]

(* Out[57]= 3.69482*10^-13 *)

Upshot: machine precision matrix products will beat iterated vector products by a wide margin. To the point where it did not matter that I discard nearly half the computed elements.

Comment: Sorry to reply late. Your solution is amazing. But I dont understand the meaning of `Drop[#1, -(#2[[1]] - 1)]` inside your code. Could you give explanation on it?

Comment: For `MapIndexed` over a list, the list position is given by that `#2[[1]]`. We use the list position to determine how much to shift rightward and replace by zeros (the `Drop` and `PadLeft` do this).